# Undefined property: App\Mail\DueReminder::$userdata in mailable

Tags: laravel

I got this error trying to pass data from controller to mailable to mail template:

This is my Mailable code:

```
class DueReminder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($dat)
    {
        $this->userdata = $dat;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('test@gmail.com', 'Test')
            ->subject('Test: Testing')
            ->view('email.sendReminder',['data1' => $this->userdata]);
    }
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
$when = now()->addMinutes(10);
$mails = User::join('courselist','courselist.coordinator','=','users.id')->join('course','courselist.course_id','=','course.id')->select('users.name','users.staffid','users.email','course.course_code','course.course_name')->where([['faculty_code','=',$slt_faculty->faculty_code],['role_id','=',2]])->get();

foreach($mails as $dat)
{
    Mail::to($dat['email'])->later($when,new DueReminder($dat));
}
```

Edit: I used send method it works but I want delayed mail that why I use later.

Answer (score 0):

your forgot to define a `public` property `$userdata` like `public $userdata`

so your code will be

```php
class DueReminder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $userdata;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($dat)
    {
        $this->userdata = $dat;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('test@gmail.com', 'Test')
            ->subject('Test: Testing')
            ->view('email.sendReminder',['data1' => $this->userdata]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes my page not found...idk why exactly

Comment: what page it is `mailable` ? right

Comment: yeah i think so

Comment: I search it up maybe it because of `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` in env. file. Is there any other ways that does not require changing this?

Comment: what error your getting can you send me ?

Comment: 404 not found...basically I make a button to send email when I press it, the error pops up